# I can't compile a .sv file (SystemVerilog)

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

I'm learning SystemVerilog for the university. I installed the extensions in Visual Studio Code for syntax highlighting: SystemVerilog, Verilog-HDL/SystemVerilog/Bluespec SystemVerilog (Names of extensions).
I installed the compiler Icarus Verilog and inserted the address in the environment variables (PATH).

So I copied this code:

```
module adder
(s, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
    input logic [7:0] a;
    input logic [7:0] b;
    input logic c_in;
    output logic [7:0] sum;
    output logic c_out;

    logic [8:0] result;

    assign result = a + b + c_in;
    assign sum = result [7:0];
    assign c_out = result[8];

endmodule: adder
```

And tried to run it, but it gave me this error:

```
Module end labels require SystemVerilog.
```

I even tried to compile from the cmd with the same result.

A thing that I noticed is that when I do the same thing with a `.v` file (Verilog), it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get a compile error in your port list.  Change:

```
(s, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
```

to:

```
(a, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
```

You didn't declare `a` in the list, and you use `a` in the code.  `s` is not in the code.

After that change, your code is legal SystemVerilog syntax, and it compiles without errors on multiple simulators on edaplayground.

I did get different compile errors from yours with Icarus Verilog 0.10.0 on edaplayground.  Perhaps you are compiling with a different version.  Keep in mind that `iverilog` does not support all SV features yet.

If the module label is still causing problems for you, you can simply remove it because it is optional.  Change:

```
endmodule: adder
```

to:

```
endmodule
```

Regarding the file extensions (`.v` and `.sv`), some compilers will automatically enable SV features when you use `.sv`; perhaps some even require `.sv`.  Since your code uses an SV keyword (`logic`), you must have SV features enabled to compile.

---

Here is a version of your code that does not rely on SV features:

```
module adder
(a, b, c_in, sum, c_out);
    input [7:0] a;
    input [7:0] b;
    input c_in;
    output [7:0] sum;
    output c_out;

    wire [8:0] result;

    assign result = a + b + c_in;
    assign sum = result [7:0];
    assign c_out = result[8];
endmodule
```

Using `logic` in the port declarations is optional, and you can declare `result` as a `wire`.